# Comparing strings between two proccess, looking to find strings that do not match

Tags: memory, process

I'm looking forward to create/run a program or maybe a script that allows you to compare two processes strings, the comparison would come from a `.txt` file, let me elaborate.

- I have a `.txt` file with over 400.000+ strings from a memory's process.(Those being saved by Process Hacker 2)
- My goal is to open **two instances** of `X` process; process named `X1` will be a clean process (or just call it vanilla) and process named `X2` will be the same process but in this instance it will be infected/hacked/modified.
- Process `X2` is infected as mentioned before, but will try to self-destruct and try to restore as an original `X1` process. Of course it's not 100% perfect and it will leave strings that never should of existed in an original `X1` process.
- Basically, I have to test all the 400.000+ strings on each process one by one, if any of the strings show at `X1`(clean file) it means the process itself starts with that specific string and it's all good (the string is discarded); on the other hand if the string **does not** show up in process `X1` but **does** in `X2` it automatically means the process is infected.

Why is so complicated to find the non-vanilla strings from `X2` process?

- Because the 'X2' process self-destructs the infected files and tries to revert it back to the original process, trying to look like the `X1` process.

What I'm looking for is to find that short amount of strings that won't be erased when self-destructed, so whenever you check both processes you find the ones that are not original from the process, and as a result, claim the process was infected.

Extra info: the process I'm looking to analyze is java, but that's just irrelevant if we're talking about general process' memory.

Comment: Would you not have added java tag ?

Comment: Yeah I added it when I first made the post because that was the process I am looking for. Removed the java tag because the the process type is irrelevant. Sorry any inconvenience.